# Fetch rows from websqldatabase

Tags: cordova, web-sql, local-database

I'm using websqldatabase in phonegap(windows phone) to store data at local end. Database creation/table creation and records insertion in tables is working fine. The issue is occurring while fetching inserted records from my table. After executing my select query the function is neither calling success callback nor error callback. I'm not sure what am I missing in the code. Here is my source code:

```
function readFromDatabase(){
  try {
  alert("In readFromDB Before");
  var db = window.openDatabase("SurveryAppDB", "1.0", "surveydb", 1000000);
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM PROJECTS;", [], successFetch, errorFetch);
  alert("After execution");
  });
  }
  catch(e) {
  alert("Unknown error "+e+".");
  }
  }
  setTimeout(function () { readFromDatabase() }, 500); 

 function successFetch(tx, resultSet){
  alert("before display rows in success");
  displayRows(resultSet.rows);
  }

  function errorFetch(tx, error){
  alert("Error processing SQL: "+JSON.stringify(error));
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: The syntax looks correct, however I've no experience of websql on the windows phone platform - I'd suggest stepping with [remote debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2014/07/21/how-to-remotely-debug-and-profile-the-performance-of-your-html5-websites-amp-apps-on-windows-phone.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the link you provided explains the way to debug any website in the emulator browser. Not at all relevent to my issue.

Comment: It's entirely relevant - your Cordova app runs inside a WebView on the device which means you can use the same technique to remote debug an HTML5 app as for a mobile website on either an emulator or physical Windows Phone device - [see here also](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/04/diagnosing-mobile-website-issues-on-windows-phone-8-1-with-visual-studio.aspx)....